# Copying Div Contents into Second Div

Tags: javascript, html

How can I clone all the contents of a div (including memory data for input's or other tags) and place them into another div?

I tried using the `innerHTML` property, but that doesn't copy any information entered into text boxes in the meantime.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain javascript: use `var clone = [somediv].cloneNode(true)`. Be sure to change the id of the clone, if applicable! `cloneNode(true)` will copy all properties and child nodes of the original, afiak it will also copy the values of input fields. It will not copy handlers assigned to the original element. See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.cloneNode)

I've edited [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/e62sw/) (intented to answer another SO-question) to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.clone(true)`:
http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: jQuery tag is not present, make sure jQuery is an option for him

Comment: ah cool, are there any non jquery variants (the library isn't used in this project, would seem mad to load it just for one thing)

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery, you can use

```
var clone = cloneNode(true);
```

and then append that node whereever you like such as

```
var targetNode = documentGetElementById('someID');
targetNode.appendChild(clone);
```